# How to evenly distribute the DAGs runs execution during the day

Tags: scheduler, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a huge amount of DAGS (>>100.000) that should each run once a day.
In order to not have big spikes in processing at certain times during the day (and other reasons) I would like to have the actual DAG runs be distributed evenly throughout the day.
Do I need to do this programmatically by myself distributing the start_date throughout the day or is there a better way where Airflow does that for me?

Comment: One possibly solution:  If you create one or more pools, each with a limited number of slots you can effectively set a 'maximum parallelism' of execution, and tasks will wait until a slot is available.   

However, it may not give you quite enough flexibility you need

Comment: @RobinL Please make this the answer

Answer (score 0):

One possibly solution: If you create one or more pools, each with a limited number of slots you can effectively set a 'maximum parallelism' of execution, and tasks will wait until a slot is available. However, it may not give you quite enough flexibility you need